# MySql saving Mobile submitted text with Weird Characters using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, iphone, mobile, encoding

I have an iPhone XS that I'm testing this with, but for some reason when I submitted a text input on my site it is being saved on MySql with some encoding that I can't figure out how to stop.

For example, I type in the text input

```
Why isn't this "working"
```

MySql saves that in the database as

```
Why isn&rsquo;t this &ldquo;working&rdquo;
```

I have changed the mysql database to UTF8_general_ci
I have added the UTF-8 meta tag

I tested to see where the problem was happening, but when I test the AJAX response, it returns correctly. The only time in the process that it is changed to that is saving in the MySql DB. I tried running the query "SET NAMES utf8".

But nothing works. Any experience with this issue out there. It only happens when I use my mobile device. It works fine on my laptop.

Comment: run the strings via urldecode() first https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: that is html, so where do you get your text from, before trying to insert it.

Comment: Running it through urldecode worked. Thanks, saved me a bunch of time!

Comment: Those are "html entities".  They do not come from MySQL; the utf8 things you mentioned are irrelevant, though probably otherwise 'correct'.